# Android Notification Icon Not Changing

Tags: android, notifications

I have tried to change the icon on my Notification class several times, unfortunately it is setting the app icon that was set on the manifest, not the one I've assigned. Has anybody experienced this before? In this manner the icon scales to a larger (xhdpa) size in the status bar.

```
Notification n = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
```

Comment: change the icon into notification.that's it

Comment: yes ive changed that serveral times

R.drawable.icon1 or R.drawable.icon2

Comment: and also your `Notification` using `Builder` for this go to my this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878091/notifications-builder-in-android-2-3/21878160#21878160](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878091/notifications-builder-in-android-2-3/21878160#21878160)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used `NotificationCompat.Builder` and for this you need to import `support-v4-library` into you project.

```
int notifyID = 1;
int icon = R.drawable.logo;
int icon_small = R.drawable.logo;
String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.logo);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Login.class);

 Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(icon_small)
                    .setTicker("ticker")
                    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText("message")
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    //At most three action buttons can be added
                    .setAutoCancel(true).build();
```

And for more information go to my answer:[Notifications Builder in android 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878091/notifications-builder-in-android-2-3/21878160#21878160)

Comment: (banghead) i still get the same result, eventhough i added a drawable-nodpi folder with an icon(24x24)

Comment: try to add the icon image into drawable folder and try

Comment: oh man! i really need a sleep, it turns out that its calling a different class, apologize for the waste of time

Comment: haha, actually i was working with parse push service. and ive enabled the built in one, thats why its not prompting to my custom broadcastreceiver :D

Answer (score 0):

Hope it works for you :)

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!");
// Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MYDEMOACTIVITY.class);

// The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
// started Activity.
// This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
// your application to the Home screen.
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
stackBuilder.addParentStack(MYDEMOACTIVITY.class);
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

And add support library v4 into your project and also import

```
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be usefull

```
NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder;

    nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Heading")
                    .setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500).setContentText(message)
                    .setAutoCancel(true).setTicker("Notification")
                    .setVibrate(new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 250, 100, 250 })
                    .setSound(alarmSound);
```